# Textbox custom string for accounting values

Tags: c#, casting, textbox, decimal

I have problem for textbox casting to integer.

I want to sum or difference two decimal double or float number but i can't.

I used a lot of keypress event handler.But every time lose.

I want to make a textbox like default calculator of windows. And i want to this format `xx.xxx,xx`

ex : `15.000,25 + 25.000,50`   = `40.000,75`

Let's check example GİF : http://gifyu.com/images/16c0a3.gif

How can i do this easily?
Thank you very much.

```
  private void tbKidemTutari_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double value;

        if (double.TryParse(tbKidemTutari.Text, out value))
        {
            tbKidemTutari.Text = String.Format("{0:0.##}", value);
        }
        else
        {
            // Some code to handle the bad input (not parsable to double)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code of what you've tried?

Comment: Hi, Mitozan. You'll need to share your code, but the best I can do without that is to direct you towards a google search on https://www.google.com/#q=c-sharp+int+parse+international+currency+format

Comment: Sorry, i added code snippets